# How to open home page in current tab (Firefox extension)

Tags: firefox, navigation

I try three possibilities:
1)

```
browser.home();
```

2. 

```
var a = browser.tabs.executeScript(tab_id, {code: 'location.href = "about:home";'});
```

3. 

```
var a = browser.tabs.executeScript(tab_id, {code: 'window.home();'});
```

All three was invoked in background script. No one working.

Answer (score 0):

I do not find this solution, but someone else response to my question about that in different place:
https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/read-homepage-url-or-load-home-page/71664/2